# Маркеры с комментариями поверх изображения

Tags: html, css

Нужно реализовать маркеры с комментариями поверх изображения, как на фото ниже. Я понимаю, как это сделать через position absolute, но предполагается, что сайт будет адаптивный и тогда позиции элементов нужно менять динамически.

Можно ли как-то "привязать" маркеры к определенной части изображения? Если нет, то как лучше это осуществить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант можно позиционировать маркеры в процентном соотношении с шириной экрана. Например с помощью viewpoint ед. измерения. Ну или высчитывать с помощью JS

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1048075/188366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему бы не сделать так? Всё в процентном соотношении. Небольшая погрешность (сдвиг элементов) есть при уменьшении размера окна, но она практически даже и незаметна, и то, если только внимательно всматриваться. Сомневаюсь, что кто-то это будет делать.

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1108px;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1%;
  height: 2%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#dot1 {
  top: 49%;
  left: 30%;
}

#dot2 {
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 30%;
}

#dot3 {
  top: 56%;
  left: 80%;
}

.dot span:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.dot span {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 32px;
  right: -2px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="img"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na5jm.png">
  <div id="dot1" class="dot"><span>Маркер 1</span></div>
  <div id="dot2" class="dot"><span>Маркер 2</span></div>
  <div id="dot3" class="dot"><span>Маркер 3</span></div>
</div>
```